# Build Order in Output Window Missing with Lightweight Solution Load

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, solution, output-window

I've toggled back and forth between normal solution load and lightweight solution load. In the latter, when I go to the output window, the **Show output from** dropdown does not have the *Build Order* view.

Is this a bug, by design (because something about the lightweight-ness prevents this option), or is there something else I need to do to enable it?

I'd like to enjoy the quick load time, but have the build order available when trying to know which error to fix first.

**EDIT**

On a different solution, *Build Order* shows up in the dropdown, but during and after a build, the output is empty. Switching back to *Build* shows that the solution built because the build outputs show up.